# Why does R plot_ly heatmap extend x limits of my data?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I wanted to render the following content in a heatmap rather than a countour plot:

[image]

When I render the same content via:

```
p2 <- plot_ly(x=xplot,y=yplot,z=zplot,type="heatmap",zsmooth="best")
```

I get

[image]

I've verified that the limits of `xplot` are 100 and 200.

Why does plot_ly show the x-axis ranging from 50 to 250?  I thought maybe it had to do with the way data gets "z-smoothed", but the y-axis seems to be untouched.

---

The dataset I am trying to plot has 2,500 points, but I believe you should be able to see the same behavior with the following data:

```
xplot = c(100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200)
yplot = c(98, 100, 184, 188, 192, 196, 200)
zplot = c(557740.27, 562123.04,  23871.66,  24987.45,  25735.05,  26106.02,  26095.27)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that others can try it out and see what is happening.

Comment: I added what I think will reproduce the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R and most other plotting packages try very hard to automatically guess your x and y axes limits so your data "looks nice" and is not squished up against the edge, but sometimes they get it wrong.

Without seeing the full data, it's hard to guess what exactly will fix it, but the [plotly documentation](https://plot.ly/r/axes) section on "Manual Ranges" indicates modifying the axes will help:

```
p2 <- plot_ly(x=xplot,y=yplot,z=zplot,type="heatmap",zsmooth="best") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(range=c(100,200),
    yaxis = list(range=c(80,200)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I also was able to find out from the plotly.js documentation that ``zsmooth="best"`` interpolates in data space and ``"fast"`` interpolates in pixel space.  From the javascript code ([here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/51a479bba976f84835bbebf566bd534930d1956c/src/traces/heatmap/plot.js#L351-L388)) it would seem that the x-data is treated differently than the y-data.